# CSS scale only width of element on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, hover

I have a button component in react that I want to scale it's width by x% of its current width using css only?

By this, I mean that I want to be able to get it's current width somehow and add like 20% of that width to the current width. Is this possible in CSS?

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, Wrapper } from "./Styles";

const CallToAction = ({ buttonText}) => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <a href="https://forms.gle/TUAru4rc8UMmSFZz6" target="_blank">
        <Button>{buttonText}</Button>
      </a>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

CallToAction.defaultProps = {
  buttonText: "Get Started",
};

export default CallToAction;
```

CSS

```
import styled from "styled-components";

export const Wrapper = styled.div`
  padding: 0rem 10rem 3rem;
  text-align: center;

  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    padding: 0rem 1rem 4rem;
  }
`;

export const Button = styled.button`
  background: #1e1e1e;
  border-radius: 69px;
  border: none;
  font-family: "Poppins";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 21px;
  color: #D98D30;
  padding: 1.25rem 5rem;
  transition: 0.1s;

  &:hover {
    // something here
  }
`;
```

Comment: You could scale its transform across the x.see moz docs here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scaleX

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to achieve that is by using CSS `transform:scaleX()`.
you can pass 1.2 to it as a parameter, which adds 20% of the current width to the total width.
the code you are looking for is:
`button:hover{ transform:scaleX(1.2) }`